# Wavelab is using an inappropriate hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

Wavelab is a music editor. I'm unable to do any processing due to it trying to use a partition as temporary storage (that is my **guess**).

I have recently formatted my computer. I then reinstalled WaveLab 6.

Some time after I realised that I had about 6 hard drives showing - it turned out some of the partitions were incorrect so I went into Disk Manager and removed some of the un-needed partitions. All works fine.

Weeks later, I needed to do some music editing and there I discovered the problem. The issue is though when I try to do almost anything in Wavelab, such as processing, it provides the following error message

> There is not enough disk space on partition E.
>   The following error code was reported by Windows: 112 ("There is not enough space on the disk.")

As mentioned, I'm guessing it's using this location as a temporary location.

My question is, does anyone know how I can tell Wavelab to use a different file location (such as a hard drive with adequate room)? Or do I simply need to increase the size of the partition?

**Edit**
I checked the Wavelab options but I find no where I can change the file location

Comment: Does that partition exist? How much space is left on it? Did you check the Wavelab options?

Comment: I will need to double check if the location exists - I think it must do because for very very small processing it works fine. In this case I was normalising an entire album (1 hours worth). I edited my question thanks to you comment :) I can't find any option to change this location @Seth

Comment: You're saying that you need to check whenever or not exists while in the question you're asking if resizing the partition would be an option. It shouldn't be hard to check if a drive with the drive letter E exists. [The manual for Wavelab Studio 6](ftp://ftp.steinberg.de/Download/WaveLab_Studio_6/Docs_English/GB_Wavelab%20Studio%206.pdf) would indicate that options are available.

Comment: I can't believe I missed it... I will try when back in the studio today, thanks @Seth, but I suspect that is the answer

Comment: Did it help? If it did, consider checking out [what to do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I wouldn't know how active you are. In addition this really was meant as a question whenever it helped or not. After all I might have misunderstood, it could've been a different problem or a number of other things. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not entirely clear whenver the drive in question still exists or not, it seems like the [official documentation for Wavelab Studio 6](ftp://ftp.steinberg.de/Download/WaveLab_Studio_6/Docs_English/GB_Wavelab%20Studio%206.pdf) include instructions on how to change temporary directories.

> WaveLab Studio allows you to specify up to three different
>   folders for storing temporary files. If you have access
>   to more than one drive, saving your temp files on separate
>   drives (not partitions) can considerably speed up performance.
>
> ...
>
> - Select “Folders…” from the Options menu.
>     This opens the Folders dialog, where you can edit how various WaveLab
>     Studio folders are handled .
> - Click on the plus sign beside the “Temporary folders”
>     item (this is located in the “Work folders” category).
>     Three possible folders can be specified for temp files.
> - Selecting one of the Temporary Folder items will show
>     the current location where the temp files will be created in
>     the Folder field to the right.
> - Either type in the path to the directory or you can
>     browse the drives to locate and select the folder via a
>     standard Windows file dialog.
>     Click OK to select a folder and exit the file dialog.